# Can I implement an iPad drop down UITableViewController if I'm not using a UISplitView?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am making my first iPad application, and I need to add the functionality of a drop-down menu. On the iPhone, I would have just used a standard UIPickerView. But on the iPad, it seems as though that is no longer the UIElement of choice. Can I implement a drop-down UITableView such as ones that are common in the UISplitView without having a UISplitView?

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the [UIPopoverViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is for. It is what UISplitView uses to show its drop downs.